# Name for those linear combinations whose scalars multipliers summing to $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Is there a general name for a linear combination of vectors $x_{1},\dots, x_{n}$ of the form $\sum_{1}^{n}c_{i}x_{i}$ where $\sum_{1}^{n}c_{i} = 1$? Considering probabilistic terminology, one may link this to the concept of expectation. But still  I would like to know if there is in literature a name for it?

Answer (score 4):

With the additional constraint that each $c_i$ is non-negative, the concept you are looking for is [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination).

Comment: Thanks :). Indeed.

Comment: Without the sign condition, it's an *affine combination*.